# How do I configure Ubuntu 14.04 to start a service automatically?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I'm not so familiar with Ubuntu and I'd like to ask how to set a process to start automatically after reboots. The service already shows up in "service --status-all" so I believe it is installed into the management system by the installer. The service can be started manually by executing "sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start".

How do I start it automatically?

Ubuntu version is 14.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `update-rc.d` command.

`sudo update-rc.d kurento-media-server-6.0 defaults`